# ‘I couldn’t agree more.’ (Is this sentence 'past tense' or 'present tense'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, interpretation

> ‘I couldn’t agree more.’

Is this sentence 'past tense' or 'present tense' We need 'context'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tense of a clause is the tense of its finite verb.  In this case, the finite verb is the modal "could".  ("Agree" here is a bare infinitive and so has no tense.)

Morphologically (and for some purposes grammatically), "could" is the past tense of "can".  However, some people prefer to think of "can" and "could" as separate modal verbs (and therefore as not having tense in any meaningful sense).  Obviously, semantically, "could" by no means refers exclusively to past time, and it *probably* doesn't do so here.  Its meaning here is probably conditional (*couldn't agree more* = "would not be able to agree more"), although it could also be past ("yesterday, when we discussed this, you'll recall that I couldn't agree more" = wasn't able to agree more), but the past-time interpretation is less likely.

Still, overall, I would say that, if forced to state what tense this modal is, I'd say it's the past tense.

*Note:* I agree that the speaker is probably referring to present time, but tense and time are not the same thing.  Tense is grammatical, time is semantic.  "I am going to see him tomorrow" is present tense; "I fly next Thursday" is also present tense. In "If I knew, I would tell you", "knew" is past tense, but refers to a hypothetical present rather than the past.

Answer (score 1):

The modal verb *could* is the politer relation of *can*, especially in requests, e.g. "Could you open the window, please?” “Could you lend me a hand?”

In “***I couldn't agree more***”, *couldn't* is used as an intensifier, it means "absolutely" or "totally" as in ***I totally agree with you***. I agree so much so, it would be *impossible* to express this agreement more *completely*.

It's unusual–not impossible–just unusual, to use *can* in "I cannot agree more".

Without any context, we can surmise that the speaker is referring to the present. But without context, it's quite possible the speaker is referring to a past situation or a previous discussion.